# PAUSE does not work on Windows 8 Batch files

Tags: windows-8, batch-file

I'm transferring some BAT files over to my Windows 8 computer from my Windows 7 Computer.  To my surprise, the Pause command does not work.  The following BAT file, which I use to review LogCat entries in Eclipse, is an example.  How can I Pause in Windows 8?

```
CD C:\ADTBundle\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\platform-tools>
adb logcat debug:* ActivityManager:E *:s
Pause
```

EDIT: Ken Wolfe saw fit to remove the Android tag.  I'm putting it back on because it appears that the pause does not work on Windows 8 only if we are executing the adb!!  So, other Android developers that can't deal with the crappy LogCat window in Eclipse who use Windows 8 should have this problem also (unless I'm the only one).

Comment: What does it do then at the pause command? Just continue?

Comment: I bet [adb is another batch file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/04/16/9551818.aspx).

Comment: I think you need `more`: `adb logcat debug:* ActivityManager:E *:s | more`

Comment: my point is that this very bat file works fine on Windows 7 (and more didn't make any difference

Comment: Raymond: adb is an exe

Comment: I use PAUSE everyday on Windows 8 with no such problem.  Put a PAUSE as the first line of your bat file and I am sure that will work.  Most likely the pause is somehow being intepreted as part of the previous lines.  Is there a non-standard EOL involved?  In your example... do you really want the ">" at the end of the line?

Comment: RGuggisberg:  You solved the problem!  It was the crappy > at the end of the first line.  I don't know where that came from.  I just know that it's ok in Win7.  Thanks!!

Comment: @RGuggisberg Maybe you should post that as an answer? Also, I'd suggest using the `/D` switch on `CD` here for the off chance that the file gets run while you're working in a different drive.

Answer (score 1):

I use PAUSE everyday on Windows 8 with no such problem. Put a PAUSE as the first line of your bat file and I am sure that will work. Most likely the pause is somehow being intepreted as part of the previous lines. Is there a non-standard EOL involved? In your example... do you really want the ">" at the end of the line?

Comment: Maybe the `>` was a remainder of `> nul` in an attempt to suppress output. Good find though.